# How do i get a refresh_token with every request with Google API

Tags: php, google-api

I am requesting offline access via the javascript api.

```
      gapi.load('auth2', function(){
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
          client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
          scope: 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
        })
        // Create button 
        $('#signinButton').click(function() {
          auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage', 'approval_prompt': 'force'}).then(onSignIn);
        });
      })
```

This gives me a code, which I then send to my server.

I then use PHP/Pulkitjalan google library/wrapper to call a new client.  (which is initialized with offline access as well)

```
$client = Google::getClient()
if(isset($input['code'])){
  $new_creds = $client->authenticate($input['code']);
}
```

This returns a valid access token.  However, its missing the refresh_token field, so that I can make another offline request in the future.  I obviously cant use the old refresh_token I just used, because i get

```
{error: invalid grant, error_description: bad request}
```

How can I get a new refresh_token when I request a new token???
Im requesting offline accessd at both the javascript api, and in the server client initialization.  What gives??

**SOLVED**

For anyone interested, this was solved, by not setting $new_creds directly from the authenticate method.  Instead I called getAccessToken to get the full token, with refresh_token, and applied that to $new_creds

```
$client = Google::getClient()
if(isset($input['code'])){
   $client->authenticate($input['code']); 
   $new_creds = $client->getAccessToken();
}
```